# Prevent linking of mallocr.o file within libc.a

Tags: c, gcc, malloc, linker-errors, multiple-definition-error

This is for my company, so I'm leery of being too specific, but I'll try.

I am attempting to add support for some existing ANSI C code to our platform. I am using GCC 4.7.2 as well as the GNU linker. We use part of newlib, but also some other C libraries, specifically `libc.a`. The end goal of this is to get an EXE or ELF image (this is for a PowerPC architecture micro) to put into the micro's RAM. This is being done on Windows XP. I am simply using a batch file, not a build environment or toolchain.

One of my build errors is a multiple definition problem of malloc/free functions. The cmd window spits out the error that there are definitions of these in both `malloc.o` and `mallocr.o`. Both of these are within `libc.a`. I've been told the "r" in `mallocr.o` is for reentrancy. I've also been told our platform does not support reentrancy.

I'm trying to resolve this error by preventing the linking of `mallocr.o` from within `libc.a`. This is the part where I am lost, I don't know how to do this. Google hasn't turned up anything helpful, and I haven't found a question on this site yet that answers my problem. I don't know if this is even possible.

There is really no specific code snippet to include in this question. Below is the error from the cmd window. I've *'d out company specific things I am not comfortable sharing.

```
c:\***\platform\2_2_0_r2013-2_x86-32\tools\gcc_4_7_2\ppc\bin\..\powerpc-eabi\lib\libc.a(mallocr.o): In function `free':
mallocr.c:(.text+0x19c): multiple definition of `free'
c:\***\platform\2_2_0_r2013-2_x86-32\tools\gcc_4_7_2\ppc\bin\..\powerpc-eabi\lib\libc.a(malloc.o):malloc.c:(.text+0x28): first defined here
c:\***\platform\2_2_0_r2013-2_x86-32\tools\gcc_4_7_2\ppc\bin\..\powerpc-eabi\lib\libc.a(mallocr.o): In function `malloc':
mallocr.c:(.text+0x468): multiple definition of `malloc'
c:\***\platform\2_2_0_r2013-2_x86-32\tools\gcc_4_7_2\ppc\bin\..\powerpc-eabi\lib\libc.a(malloc.o):malloc.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
```

Comment: Your Linker should support either weak linking or just a switch to ignore these. In which case the library linked first (in the command line) will provide the symbols.

Comment: one possibility is to simply remove the reference to mallocr.c from the linker command.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not a direct reference to mallocr.c. The reference is to libc.a, and the object file is within this library file.